# Hibernate default varchar value - Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a Postgres database that i have mapped with Hibernate, and everything was working fine until i had the need of adding a new attribute.
I've added an attribute "ROLE" which needs to be not null and have the value "USER" by default.
In Postgres i have `ROLE VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER'` which i believe is correct, and i also have

```
@Column(name = "role", length = 60, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(60) default 'USER'")
public String getRole() {
    return this.role;
}
```

The thing is, when i try to create a new entry in my DB it fails - `not-null property references a null or transient value`

I've tried everything but no luck... From what i read, what i have should have worked.
Can anyone help please?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried with a different name but still fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most cases it should work out if you just set the role to your default value.

Otherwise it will be set to `null` as `this.role` will be `null` during save and so that value will get persisted.

- Default value as initial value of the field:

  ```
  private String role = "USER";
  ```
- Use a `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType` and override `null` during save:

  ```
  @Override
  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
  {
      if (value == null)
          st.setString(index, "ROLE");
      else
          st.setString(index, s);
  }
  ```
- Use a `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` method and set the default value with:

  ```
  if (this.role == null) { this.role = "USER"; }
  ```

If you get objects with that value set to null from outside like deserialized JSON or XML you might need to use `@PrePersist` or a `UserType`, otherwise just setting the default value should be fine.

- You could use Hibernates dynamic update statement `dynamic-update=true` and `dynamic-insert=true`. It generates insert statements for each insert that dosn't insert null values and thus uses the DB default value.

Comment: But i have another attribute, a boolean, that i just did `columnDefinition = "boolean default false"`... can you please explain me why it works with a boolean and not with a varchar?

Comment: The default value of a `boolean` is `false`, that's why :-) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html